# Integration with generalized spherical coordinates

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define $\varphi:(0,\infty)\times S^n\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $\varphi(t,\theta)=t\theta$. Let $E$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and let $E_r\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ contain all points $\theta\in S^n$ such that $t\theta\in E$ for some $t>0$. Then $\int_{E}fdx_1...dx_{n+1}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{E_r}f\circ\varphi \ r^ndrdv$, where $dv$ is the volume form of the n sphere.

I'm with the classical change of variable. For this, I need to know why the determinant of $D\varphi=r^n$, but I don't see an easy way of seeing this.

Comment: You will also need a constant; the Jacobian is not $r^n$, it is $C_n r^n$, where $C_n$ is the surface measure of the $n$-sphere.

Comment: "Let $E_r \subseteq \Bbb R^{n+1}$ contain all points $\theta \in S^n$ such that $t\theta \in E_r$ for some $t>0$". Could you please explain what this means?

Comment: @PaulSinclair sorry, there was a typo. I've fixed it.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro - that constant $C_n$ comes from the integration over $S^n$. In this case, the integration is only over $E_r$, and has yet to be performed,

Comment: Right; the Jacobian is $r^n$, not $C_nr^n$. Sorry for my mistake. Concerning the question, I prefer to see it in terms of metric tensors; $$ds^2=dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2, $$where $ds^2$ is the metric tensor of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, and $d\theta^2$ is the metric tensor of $\mathbb S^n$. This can be seen by expanding $ds^2=(d(r\theta))^2.$ Then, the volume form formula follows from $$dx=\sqrt{g}drd\theta, $$ where $g$ is the determinant of $ds^2$. Not too rigorous, but faster for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the meaning of $E_r$ is cleared up, I can say with certainty that your iterated integral formula makes no sense. There is a small problem that the integrals are backwards from the differentials. ($r$ does not vary over $E_r$, nor does $v$ vary over $(-\infty, \infty)$.)

But the real issue is that the region of integration for iterated integral does not match $E$ at all. To give the correct expression, you need to define another collection of sets $$E(\theta) = \{ t \in \Bbb R : t\theta \in E, t > 0\}\quad\forall \theta \in E_r$$
(I didn't want to use $E_\theta$ because $E(\theta)$ depends on $\theta$, while the previously established "$E_r$" does not depend on $r$.) Then the actual formula would be
$$\int_{E}fdV=\int_{E_r}\int_{E(\theta)}f\circ\varphi \ r^n\,dr\,dv$$

If you turned it around: Let $E_r \subseteq S^n$ and let $E = \{t\theta : \theta \in E_r, t > 0\}$ (i.e., $E$ is the union of all rays passing through $E_r$), then you could justify the equation
$$\int_{E}fdV=\int_0^\infty\int_{E_r}f\circ\varphi \ r^n\,dv\,dr$$
since $E(\theta) = (0,\infty)$ for all $\theta$ in this case. But there is no way to justify integrating $r$ over $(-\infty, \infty)$.

---

As for your differential question, informally: $dr$ is the direction perpendicular to $rS^n$, the sphere of radius $r$, so the volume element at radius $r$ is $dr$ times the "$n$-area" $dw$ on $rS^n$. But $rS^n$ is just $S^n$ magnified by a factor of $r$, so every one of its $n$ independent directions is scaled by $r$, and therefore, its differential area is $r^n$ times as big as the corresponding differential area $dv$ on $S^n$.

To make that handwaving rigorous, define an orthonormal coordinate system on $S^n$. For instance, $(\theta_1, ..., \theta_n)$, where $$x_0 = \sin\theta_1 ... \sin\theta_n\\x_1 = \cos\theta_1\sin \theta_2 ... \sin \theta_n\\x_2 = \cos\theta_2\sin \theta_3 ... \sin \theta_n\\\vdots\\x_n = \cos \theta_n$$
And therefore $$\varphi(r,\theta_1, ..., \theta_n) = (r\sin\theta_1 ... \sin\theta_n, r\cos\theta_1\sin \theta_2 ... \sin \theta_n, ..., r\cos\theta_n)$$
Now you have something concrete to base your Hessian calculation on.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to see this in terms of metric tensors; $$\tag{1}ds^2=dr^2 + r^2d\theta^2, $$where $ds^2$ is the metric tensor of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, and $d\theta^2$ is the metric tensor of $\mathbb S^n$. This formula can be quickly proved by expanding $ds^2=(d(r\theta))^2=(dr\, \theta+r\,d\theta)^2, $ using that $\theta\cdot d\theta=0$, because $\theta\cdot \theta=1$.

Once (1) has been proved, the volume form formula immediately follows from $$dx=\sqrt{g}drd\theta, $$ where $g$ is the determinant of $ds^2$.

Not too rigorous, maybe, but faster.